# Is it possible to create dynamic migrations in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, migration

wondering if it is possible to run a foreach loop inside a Laravel migration file.

for instance:

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {


        $testarray = [
            'string' => 'name',
            'string' => 'lastname',
            'string' => 'random',
        ];


        $table->increments('id');

        foreach ($testarray as $type => $column)
        {
            $table->$type($column);
        }

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

unfortunately, the above will migrate; however, only the last item in the array will get created.

I have tried this a few different ways to no avail.

But....considering that, at least, some data makes it through and the migration actually runs, there should be a way to make this work.

I feel as though I must be missing something obvious to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, only the last item will be created **because you're assigning to the *"string"* index the same element many times**.

Try something like this, maybe:

```
$testarray = [
    ['string', 'name'],
    ['string', 'lastname'],
    ['string', 'random']
];

$table->increments('id');

foreach ($testarray as $column)
{
    $table->{$column[0]}($column[1]);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yea, the multidimensional approach hit me at like 3 in the morning. Thanks for the help. This approach works as intended